# MySQL does not show the Users inside the database even if they are present

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, mysql-error-1064

I have a strange problem with MySql. I did a small project with Spring-Boot MySql but when I try to add a new User to the database it gives me the success message but then going to see on mysql shell nothing appears in the database even if there is (because with the Get it actually finds the inserted user). Now I don't understand what the problem is. I attach the applications. properties of my Spring project.

every time I ask for Get it returns this **MESSAGE**:

```
D:\>curl -G localhost:8080/demo/first -d name=Biagio
{"name":"Biagio","timestamp":"2020-10-05T08:54:18.623+00:00","email":"biagio@gmal.com","surname":"Biagio2"}
```

**My Database**:

```
+----+------------------------+----------+----------------------------+---------+
| id | email                  | name     | stmp                       | surname |
+----+------------------------+----------+----------------------------+---------+
| 32 | mirketto90@yahoo.it    | Mirko    | 2020-10-01 12:31:47.827000 | NULL    |
| 36 | biagio@gmail.com       | Biagio   | 2020-10-01 16:31:31.687000 | Vaso    |
| 37 | biagio@gmail.com       | Biagio   | 2020-10-01 16:31:50.077000 | Vaso    |
| 38 | biagio@gmail.com       | Biagio   | 2020-10-01 18:35:45.992000 | Vaso    |
| 39 |                        | Mirko    | 2020-10-02 13:24:05.840000 | Vaso    |
| 40 | mirkoparioli@gmail.com | Mirko    | 2020-10-02 13:24:23.383000 | Vaso    |
| 47 | giovanni@gmal.com      | Giovanni | 2020-10-05 12:11:05.997000 | John    |
+----+------------------------+----------+----------------------------+---------+
```

I'm sure I'm using the right database (db_example), this is my

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataMysqlApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataMysqlApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

```
@RestController@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class MainController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Transactional
  //@RequestMapping(value = "/add/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @PostMapping(path = "/demo/add")
  public String addNewUser(@PathVariable("name") String name, @PathVariable("email") String email, @PathVariable("surname") String surname) {

    UserDto n = new UserDto();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setSurname(surname);
    n.setEmail(email);
    userService.create(n);
    return "User Saved in DB";
  }

  @SuppressWarnings({
    "rawtypes",
    "unchecked"
  })
  //@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchUser/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @GetMapping("/demo/first")
  public ResponseEntity < UserDto > fetchUser(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
    System.out.println(name);

    try {
      UserDto namefound = userService.findFirstByName(name);
      System.out.println("Name found");
      ResponseEntity < UserDto > user = new ResponseEntity < UserDto > (namefound, HttpStatus.OK);
      return user;
    } catch(NoResultException ne) {
      System.out.println("User not found");
      return new ResponseEntity("User not found with name : " + name, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. What do you expected in your database?

Comment: If you see well, in my database there is no Biagio with surname Biagio2, there are only names that I entered manually. Those entered via POST are not visible even if they are there and the Get is the confirmation

Comment: oh, I see now. You can print out the user id then check if this id exists in the database.

Comment: I printed the id but it doesn't exist, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. There was simply too much "private" when @Autowired on UserServiceImpl.The project is fair and well connected. For anything do not hesitate to write me.

Answer (score 1):

1. **For adding user to the database**
   Modify your path in PostMapping

   From `@PostMapping(path = "/demo/add")`
   to   `@PostMapping(path = "/demo/add/{name}/{email}/{surname}")`

   this is because in your **addNewUser** method you accept the name,email,surname as **PathVariable**.
   To bring a small clarity about the @PathVariable - it is a annotation that indicates which method parameter should be matched which URI template variable.

   In your case for example,
   **{name}** - Is the URI template variable
   String **name** in addNewUser method - Is the method parameter(which the alias name that you can use the {name} value in rest of the method)

   You must access the api like,

   ```
    localhost:8080/demo/add/Biagio/biagio@gmail.com/Vaso
   ```
2. **To get user by name** 
   Modify path in GetMapping
   Similar to above explanation,

   From `@GetMapping("/demo/first")`
   to   `@GetMapping("/demo/first/{name}")`

   You must access the api like,

   ```
    localhost:8080/demo/first/Biagio
   ```

Comment: Even doing this does not change the fact that the problem of not viewing the database remains